# typescript parentElement return value

Tags: angular, typescript

hello below you can see my code seems that getParentElement() function doesn't return an **HTMLElement** type but if I replace  it with **any** i don't have any error, but i cannot use the type any in my project for a lint problem.
Any idea?

[image]

Comment: please avoid posting screenshot since they are hard to read and you can't copy/paste the code.

Comment: you can simply type it as `element: ElementRef<Element>` If not accessible, just cast it `(this.element as ElementRef<Element>).nativeElement.closest('th').parentElement`; or `(this.element.nativeElement as Element).closest('th').parentElement` .`parentElement` is an `HTMLElement`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `this.element` is an ElementRef, I think you didn't correctly typed it. `nativeElement` returns the generic type so it should look something like this:

```
@ViewChild('element', { static: true })
element: ElementRef<HTMLElement>
```

Comment: i am inside a directive i can't use the @viewChild howeveer i just need to understand what the function getParentElement returns

Comment: It returns an HTMLElement, but because nativeElement is typed as any so is parentElement. If you can't change the type of element you can cast it like this:
(this.element.nativeElement as HTMLElement).closest('th').parentElement